# XSLT grouping on multiple keys using Muenchian method

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

This is the input file.

All these blocks are wrapped in a `<allocfile>` tag which is not appearing, dunno why? And all these blocks are wrapped in a top level element `<xml>`.

```
<XML>
  <AllocFile>
    <alc>1</alc>
    <No>11/10</No>
    <DT>20090401</DT> 
    <G_H>147</G_H>
    <FUN>125487</FUN>
    <oH>11</oH>
    <y>9</y>
    <AMOUNT>8000000</AMOUNT>
    <Code>033195</Code>
    <hd1>1234</hd1>
  </AllocFile>
  <AllocFile>
    <alc>2</alc>
    <No>14/10</No>
    <DT>20090401</DT>
    <G_H>147</G_H>
    <FUN>125487</FUN>
    <oH>11</oH>
    <y>9</y>
    <AMOUNT>8400000</AMOUNT>
    <Code>033195</Code>
    <hd1>1234</hd1>
  </AllocFile>
  <AllocFile>
    <alc>3</alc>
    <No>74/10</No>
    <DT>20090401</DT>
    <G_H>147</G_H>
    <FUN>125487</FUN>
    <oH>11</oH>
    <y>9</y>
    <AMOUNT>8740000</AMOUNT>
    <Code>033195</Code>
    <hd1>1234</hd1>
  </AllocFile>
  <AllocFile>
    <alc>2</alc>
    <No>74/10</No>
    <DT>20090401</DT>
    <G_H>117</G_H>
    <FUN>125487</FUN>
    <oH>19</oH>
    <y>9</y>
    <AMOUNT>74512</AMOUNT>
    <Code>033118</Code>
    <hd1>1234</hd1>
  </AllocFile>
  <AllocFile>
    <alc>3</alc>
    <No>14/10</No>
    <DT>20090401</DT>
    <G_H>117</G_H>
    <FUN>125487</FUN>
    <oH>19</oH>
    <y>9</y>
    <AMOUNT>986541</AMOUNT>
    <Code>033147</Code>
    <hd1>1234</hd1>
  </AllocFile> 
</XML>
```

The output is

```
<Header1>
  <Hd1>1234</Hd1>
  <CodeHeader>
    <Code>033195</Code>
    <Header2>
      <G_H>147</G_H>
      <FUN>125487</FUN>
      <oH>11</oH>
      <y>9</y>
      <allocheader>
        <alc>1</alc>
        <No>11/10</No>
        <DT>20090401</DT>
        <AMOUNT>8000000</AMOUNT>
      </allocheader>
      <allocheader>
        <alc>2</alc>
        <No>14/10</No>
        <DT>20090401</DT>
        <AMOUNT>8400000</AMOUNT>
      </allocheader>
      <allocheader>
        <alc>3</alc>
        <No>74/10</No>
        <DT>20090401</DT>
        <AMOUNT>8740000</AMOUNT>
      </allocheader>
    </Header2>
  </CodeHeader>
  <CodeHeader>
        <Code>033118</Code>
        <Header2>
      <G_H>117</G_H>
      <FUN>125487</FUN>
         <oH>19</oH>
            <y>9</y>
             <allocheader>
             <alc>2</alc>
             <No>74/10</No>
             <DT>20090401</DT>
             <AMOUNT>74512</AMOUNT>
           </allocheader>
       </Header2>
    </codeHeader>
   <CodeHeader>
        <Code>033147</Code>
           <Header2>
          <G_H>117</G_H>
          <FUN>125487</FUN>
          <oH>19</oH>
          <y>9</y>
         <allocheader>
           <alc>3</alc>
            <No>14/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>986541</AMOUNT>
          </allocheader>
         </Header2>
      </CodeHeader>
</Header1>
```

The input file needs to be sorted and grouped on the basis of multiple keys. I proceeded using the `concat` function and the Muenchian method but didn't much help from the web. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Rules for Grouping

- All the nodes in the file will have `<hd1>` with values `1234..` this becomes the first group by key and appears in the output as `<Header1>`

  - the second key for grouping is the node  code . nodes having same value get grouped together. appears as. code header
- The second key is the group of nodes `G_H`, `FUN`, `oH`, `y`. If all these have the same values for nodes, they get grouped together. It appears in the output as `<Header2>`
- No grouping happens on the nodes `<alc>`, `<No>`,  `<DT>`, `<AMOUNT>`. They have distinct values within each group.

Comment: The provided desired output isn't well-formed XML document -- please, correct.

Comment: added the </header1> tag at the end of o/p xml to make it a well formed xml doc

Comment: @Manks: You need to prefix any code samples with four spaces for it to show up. I've done this for you, so it should all display correctly now!

Comment: You say "All the nodes in the file will have `<hd1>` with values 1234"? Will this always be the case? What happens if `<hd1>` contains another value? if they are all the same, you are not really grouping by them, and only need the one key.

Comment: I have updated my current answer to cope with the expanded requirements

Comment: tons of thanks for the answer and detailed explanation :) !!! If possible can u tell me any good source to study about xslt on the web.I tried 'w3c' but its kinda ok, not too good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the **hd1** element is always '1234' then you are not really grouping by them, but if you were you would define a simple key like so

```
<xsl:key name="header1" match="AllocFile" use="hd1" />
```

For the second key, you would need to take account of the **Code** element

```
<xsl:key name="header2" match="AllocFile" use="concat(hd1, '|', Code)" />
```

And then for the last key, you would define a more complicated key to cope with all the elements

```
<xsl:key name="header3" 
   match="AllocFile" 
   use="concat(hd1 '|', Code, '|', G_H, '|', FUN, '|', oH, '|', y)" />
```

Do note the use of the 'pipe' character as the delimiter. It is important to pick a delimited that would never occur in any of the selected elements.

Then, to look for the distinct **header1** elements, you would look for the elements which appear first in the **header1** key

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="AllocFile[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header1', hd1)[1])]" 
   mode="header1" />
```

To find the distinct **Code** elements within each **header1** element, you would do the following

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="key('header1', hd1)
     [generate-id() = generate-id(key('header2', concat(hd1, '|', Code))[1])]" 
   mode="header2" />
```

Finally, within each code group, to find the distinct 'header3' elements, you would look for the first elements within the third key

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
 select="key('header2', concat(hd1, '|', Code))
    [generate-id() = 
     generate-id(key('header3', concat(hd1, '|', Code, '|', G_H, '|', FUN, '|', oH, '|', y))[1])]" 
 mode="header3" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="header1" match="AllocFile" use="hd1"/>
   <xsl:key name="header2" match="AllocFile" use="concat(hd1, '|', Code)"/>
   <xsl:key name="header3" match="AllocFile" use="concat(hd1, '|', Code, '|', G_H, '|', FUN, '|', oH, '|', y)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/XML">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AllocFile[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header1', hd1)[1])]" mode="header1"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AllocFile" mode="header1">
      <Header1>
         <Hd1>
            <xsl:value-of select="hd1"/>
         </Hd1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('header1', hd1)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header2', concat(hd1, '|', Code))[1])]" mode="header2"/>
      </Header1>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AllocFile" mode="header2">
      <CodeHeader>
         <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('header2', concat(hd1, '|', Code))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header3', concat(hd1, '|', Code, '|', G_H, '|', FUN, '|', oH, '|', y))[1])]" mode="header3"/>
      </CodeHeader>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AllocFile" mode="header3">
      <Header2>
         <xsl:copy-of select="G_H|FUN|oH|y"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('header3', concat(hd1, '|', Code, '|', G_H, '|', FUN, '|', oH, '|', y))"/>
      </Header2>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AllocFile">
      <allocheader>
         <xsl:copy-of select="alc|No|DT|AMOUNT"/>
      </allocheader>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of the **mode** attribute on the template matching to distinguish between the multiple templates all matching the **AllocFile** elements.

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<Header1>
   <Hd1>1234</Hd1>
   <CodeHeader>
      <Code>033195</Code>
      <Header2>
         <G_H>147</G_H>
         <FUN>125487</FUN>
         <oH>11</oH>
         <y>9</y>
         <allocheader>
            <alc>1</alc>
            <No>11/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>8000000</AMOUNT>
         </allocheader>
         <allocheader>
            <alc>2</alc>
            <No>14/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>8400000</AMOUNT>
         </allocheader>
         <allocheader>
            <alc>3</alc>
            <No>74/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>8740000</AMOUNT>
         </allocheader>
      </Header2>
   </CodeHeader>
   <CodeHeader>
      <Code>033118</Code>
      <Header2>
         <G_H>117</G_H>
         <FUN>125487</FUN>
         <oH>19</oH>
         <y>9</y>
         <allocheader>
            <alc>2</alc>
            <No>74/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>74512</AMOUNT>
         </allocheader>
      </Header2>
   </CodeHeader>
   <CodeHeader>
      <Code>033147</Code>
      <Header2>
         <G_H>117</G_H>
         <FUN>125487</FUN>
         <oH>19</oH>
         <y>9</y>
         <allocheader>
            <alc>3</alc>
            <No>14/10</No>
            <DT>20090401</DT>
            <AMOUNT>986541</AMOUNT>
         </allocheader>
      </Header2>
   </CodeHeader>
</Header1>
```

If you did have different **hd1** elements, other than '1234' you would end up with multiple **Header1** elements, and so your output would not be well-formed XML. It would be simple enough to wrap them in a root element though by modified the initial template matching the document element.

```
<xsl:template match="/XML">
   <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AllocFile[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header1', hd1)[1])]" mode="header1" />
   </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: the answer provided is awesome , but I missed a rule for grouping which I have added now , can u please what more modifications to the xslt is required. I tried to add one more key for code header and in the header 1  match added one more node xsl: apply templates corr. to the code header .but it gave me compilation error.

Comment: Can you expand you question a bit more, because I am not quite sure of the new requirement. The output shown in my answer currently matches the expected output in your question, you see. Thanks!

Comment: the is perfectly correct but my point was that if there are nodes with multiple <code> values , how to proceed with grouping . The Changes I made to the XSL was 1. defined a key  <xsl:key name="CodeHeader" match="AllocFile" use="concat(hd1, '|', Code)" /> and 2. and added   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('header1', hd1)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CodeHeader', concat(hd1, '|',Code))[1])]" mode="CodeHeader" />
and removed the <xsl:copy-of select="Code" /> statement .but something went wrong and its not giving the desired output .

Comment: Can you amend your input sample to show the case where there are multiple `<code>` values? Will there be a limit on the number of  `<code>` values that can appear?

Comment: I have changed the code values for the last two <allocFile> blocks. There is no limit as such it can be different for all these blocks(worst case) and can be the same also(best case).

Comment: I am beginning to understand now! But can you amend your expected output, because codes 033118 and 033147 do not appear in your output, so am I not 100% sure how you want to handle them. Thanks!

Comment: Changed the output to reflect the scenario  ..Thanks in advance

Comment: tons of thanks for the answer and detailed explanation :) !!! If possible can u tell me any good source to study about xslt on the web.I tried w3c but its kinda ok not too good.