# Convert raw input XML to structured XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I tried using XSL with "for-each"
I need to group the value based on CATEGORY and TYPE.

Any help?

**Input RAW xml:**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<ID>12345</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>1</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>12345</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>2</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO2</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>12345</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<SUBTYPE>SUBTYP2</SUBTYP>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>3</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO3</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>1</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>1</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>2</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO2</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP2</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>3</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO3</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP2</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>2</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO2</LABEL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
<TYPE>TYP2</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
<VALUE>3</VALUE>
<LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

**Expected Result:**
I need to group the values based on Category and TYPE (see below)

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<ID>12345</ID>
    <TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
    <GRP1>
    <VALUE>1</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
    <VALUE>2</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO2</LABEL>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO3</LABEL>
    </GRP1>         
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>67890</ID>
  <TYP>
    <TYPE>TYP1</TYPE>
    <TYPE>TYP2</TYPE>
  </TYP>
<CATEGORY>A1</CATEGORY>
    <GRP1>
    <VALUE>1</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO1</LABEL>
    <VALUE>2</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO2</LABEL>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    <LABEL>ISO3</LABEL>
    </GRP1>
```

**XSL used:** It needs some corrections. (Thanks to @Parfait for the code)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="categkey" match="ROW" use="CATEGORY" />

<xsl:template match="ROWSET">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each select="ROW[generate-id()= generate-id(key('categkey', CATEGORY)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="TYPE"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="CATEGORY"/>
      <GRP1>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('categkey', CATEGORY)">            
            <xsl:copy-of select="VALUE"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="LABEL"/>            
        </xsl:for-each>
      </GRP1>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Thanks!
Carthyc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grouping in XSLT 1.0, consider the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which indexes the document according to a key and can run various operations with that key:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="categkey" match="ROW" use="CATEGORY" />

  <xsl:template match="ROWSET">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="ROW[generate-id()= generate-id(key('categkey', CATEGORY)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="TYPE"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="CATEGORY"/>
          <GRP1>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('categkey', CATEGORY)">            
                <xsl:copy-of select="VALUE"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LABEL"/>            
            </xsl:for-each>
          </GRP1>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Borrowing from @Tim C's [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863491/xslt-grouping-on-multiple-keys-using-muenchian-method) (the XSLT guru who first edited your post), for multiple keys such as on `ID` and its siblings, consider the below:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="idkey" match="ROW" use="ID" />
<xsl:key name="typekey" match="ROW" use="concat(ID, TYPE)"/>
<xsl:key name="categkey" match="ROW" use="concat(ID, CATEGORY)" />
<xsl:key name="valuekey" match="ROW" use="concat(ID, VALUE)" />
<xsl:key name="labelkey" match="ROW" use="concat(ID, LABEL)" />

  <xsl:template match="ROWSET">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="ROW[generate-id()= generate-id(key('idkey', ID)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
          <TYP>            
            <xsl:for-each select="key('idkey', ID)[generate-id()= generate-id(key('typekey', concat(ID, TYPE))[1])]">            
                <xsl:copy-of select="TYPE"/>                                    
            </xsl:for-each>
          </TYP>
          <xsl:copy-of select="CATEGORY"/>

          <GRP1>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('idkey', ID)[generate-id()= generate-id(key('valuekey', concat(ID, VALUE))[1])]">
              <xsl:copy-of select="VALUE"/>          
              <xsl:copy-of select="LABEL"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </GRP1>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait. I am extending the input for two more groupings. I tried using above method with two keys defined on CATEGORY and TYPE..I didn't expected result as shown above.

Comment: See above edit using multiple keys for multiple groupings.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for..Thank you Parfait and Tim C for your help!! :)..I made few tweaks like added loop at CATEGORY level for my requirement and also modified "valuekey" to use concat(ID,CATEGORY,VALUE)..update "xsl:copy-of" with "xsl:value-of".