# Is it possible to add contitions to <xsl:key use="">?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="SHOPITEM" use="substring-before(PRODUCT, ' ')" />
```

Hello, i'm using this part of code to verify elements by first word but this is not enough.
i have to add some conditions like:

> if contains(PRODUCT, "SIZE.") then substring-before(PRODUCT, 'SIZE.')
>   else get all value of PRODUCT

is it possible to put "if" inside "use" or any other way to do that?

Comment: For 1.0
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863491/xslt-grouping-on-multiple-keys-using-muenchian-method

Check it

Comment: Your life would be much easier for this kind of thing if you were able to move to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0

Comment: Yes i know but application which i'm using in my job allows only XSLT 1.0 :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you can use a technique called [Oliver Becker's method](http://www.xml.org//sites/www.xml.org/files/xslt_efficient_programming_techniques.pdf), which means writing the `use` in this form

```
concat(
  substring(Str1,1 div Cond),
  substring(Str2,1 div not(Cond))
)
```

So, in your case, you could write your `xsl:key` like this:

```
<xsl:key name="item2" match="SHOPITEM" use="concat(
        substring(substring-before(PRODUCT, ' SIZE.'), 1 div (contains(PRODUCT, ' SIZE.'))),
        substring(PRODUCT, 1 div (not(contains(PRODUCT, ' SIZE.'))))
    )" />
```

Whether you consider this readable is another matter.

However, in this particular case, for the logic you are trying to implement, you could also write the key like this:

```
 <xsl:key name="item" match="SHOPITEM" use="substring-before(concat(PRODUCT, ' SIZE.'), ' SIZE.')" />
```

So, if the `PRODUCT` contains `SIZE.` it will find the text before the first occurrence. If not, it will the concatenated `SIZE.` which effectively get the whole string

See examples in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYij